# What feat, magic item, or spell is used to create a skeletal champion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, undead

The spell [*animate dead*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-dead/) creates a mindless skeleton. The spell [*create undead*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-undead) creates ghouls and stronger. But what feat, magic item, or spell allows the creation of a [skeletal champion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/skeletal-champion/)?

I am the GM. My players may witness a scene in which a skeletal champion is created, but what must the NPC wizard do to actually create such an intelligent adversary for the melee types?

[This thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ldk2?How-does-one-create-skeletal-champions-and) led me to [this link](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-undead) on my mobile device. I don't have [*Undead Revisited*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8l3g?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Undead-Revisited), but from what I read on the forums, it contains the canonical answer from Paizo, and *Revisited* agrees with *d20pfsrd*. Do I have that right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need is [Create Undead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-undead) (cleric/wizard 6), and either [Enervation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enervation/) (wizard 4) or [Energy Drain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/energy-drain) (cleric/wizard 9). This can be seen on [Undead Revisited](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8l3g?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Undead-Revisited) (page 3), which has an updated table on **Creating Undead**. For convenience, here is a copy of said table:

[image: Create Undead]

Which means the [table on the SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-undead) is up-to-date, and as far as I can tell, also correct.